# QML, how to access sub-meta object

Tags: qt, qml

There are `Widget.qml`, `Button.qml`,  `Label.qml`..
In `Widget.qml`, there is a `Button` meta, and In `Button.qml`, there is `Label` mata...

How can i access Label by `Button` in `Widget`...

[image: Widget.qml][image: Lable.qml]

Comment: What's a "sub-meta object"? And what have you tried in Widget.qml?

Comment: This seems to be another variant of the XY Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind properties of `Label` inside the Label itself. If you simply want to explicitly set those properties, you could put it inside a javascript function that is called when the components are created:

```
ClearButton {
    Component.onCompleted: { label.text = ... }
}
```

Or you could bind properties inside `ClearButton` and bind Label properties to the parent button:

```
ClearButton {
    id: button
    property var text: "登陆" // prefer "property string text"

    ...

    Label {
        text: button.text
        ...
    }
}
```